# Proposed change to badges: Flip the half note, center the whole note

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

I really like the idea of the badges, however the lack of stem in the whole note just makes the badges seem off. I'm sure I'll get used to it eventually, but I have a suggestion for a slight alteration that may balance the notes out. If we flip the half note we could then we can center the whole note and have it make sense.

I did a quick mock up of what it would look like on the upper menu and on each specific badge.

### Menu

#### Current:

[image]

#### Proposed:

[image]

### Individual badges

#### Current:

[image]

#### Proposed:

[image]

Better? Worse?

Comment: Much better. Thank you.

Comment: I love it. Additionally it would be good to slightly enlarge the gold badge a bit. Whole notes are often a bit wider with thicker lines at the sides, and also without the slant (or even a slight slant the other way). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_note

Comment: Just a side note: The only other site in SE I know where the badge values differs in shape in addition to color, is the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges) site. I feel we are in good company here :)

Comment: @awe I think CS also has diffrent badges

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion! I'll admit that I probably didn't take as much time as I should have to guarantee note accuracy when the new design launched. Taking your suggestion to heart, I updated the badges:

- Taking **awe**'s suggestion, I removed the rotation on the whole note.
- Taking **Dom**'s suggestion, I flipped the half note to help more visually distinguish it from the quarter note.

They will now look like this:

[image: Badges]

This will be updated in the next production build.

Comment: This looks awesome.

Comment: Love it! The first time I saw the original version I didn't realize they were different note values at all and thought it was an image compression issue causing the gold stem to "disappear". That whole note rotation is really important!

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively:

1. Make them all quarter notes for consistency, ***or***
2. Make the gold/silver/bronze badges be half/quarter/eighth notes respectively, so they all have stems.

(The above were suggested by Todd [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/cramped-badges-and-missing-gold-badge-on-meta#comment5470_2439).)

I'd be happy with either of the 3 solutions, as I do find the current incarnation makes the gold badge look out of place.

Comment: Personally I really like whole - half - quarter. I understand where the stems would be nice, but I think it'd always bug be to be unable to earn a whole note. It'd be like marching your whole life.

Comment: @Josiah LOL! I mean, what do you have against marching?

Comment: I think my favourite of the three options is the first point on this answer - but any would be an improvement.