# Upvote and Downvote icons are rests

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It would be really fun and make music stack exchange even *more* unique if the **upvote icon** on a post could be a *half-rest*, and the **downvote icon** could be a *whole-rest*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not happening. From a [Stack Exchange product manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309349):

> things like voting and favorite buttons are a core part of the Q&A experience that should be shared across the network. It was a mistake that we ever allowed for those to be themed.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be it. Now that I look back at other SE sites, they used to have themed voting buttons, but now they've all been standardized.

Answer (score 4):

While we did have some lovely customisation, Stack Exchange worked out it took far too much effort to manage all of the various customisations and have taken the official line of consolidating to one set of icons etc across every site, with an associated responsive UI.

See [Responsive design released for all Beta & Undesigned sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315662/154443)

So no, we will definitely not be getting customised icons back again. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

While I think it's a clever idea, I haven't seen any other SE site do this; it seems to me like something you'd see on Reddit, but not on SE.

This doesn't mean that SE doesn't allow it; maybe they do, and I just don't know it. But [Who decides the layout and icons of a site? Are they open to vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239755/who-decides-the-layout-and-icons-of-a-site-are-they-open-to-vote) suggests that it might not be something we could get running.

This might be another question best suited for Meta.SE, but if you ask there, make sure to make it more general: "can we request specific voting icons," not "can Music.SE request specific voting icons." Perhaps such a question already exists, but I can't find it.

Comment: We used to have the triangle fermate as the vote button  (as mentioned in the comments here https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/triangle-above-note-with-dot-in-it). Not sure what happened to it and that might be a better question to ask on this meta. We also have successfully changed features on the site in the past (like our badges https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/proposed-change-to-badges-flip-the-half-note-center-the-whole-note)

Comment: @Dom Oh, wow, I don't remember that! Did we have that right before this current re-design, or did they disappear before that?

Comment: I'm not sure when it happened. I'll see if I can find a picture of it.

Comment: It's clearly shown in a picture here: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/music-se-site-design-with-an-updated-logo-and-color